# How to change color in plot and the table of labels in plot?

Tags: r, colors, plot

```
plot(donnees.test$y,esvr1.pred,xlab = "Predicted Vlues", ylab = "Actual Values",type="p", yaxs="i",ylim=c(2,18),xaxs="i",xlim=c(2,18))
points(donnees.test$y,esvr1.pred, col=1,pch =19)
points(donnees.test$y,esvr1.pred, col=2,pch =20)
points(donnees.test$y,ANFIS, col=6,pch =3)
points(donnees.test$y,NN, col=4,pch =4)
#points(donnees.test$y,esvr1.pred, col=3)
abline(a = 0, b = 1, col = 3)
abline(a = 0, b = 1.25, col = 2)
text(9,14, "+25% Line", col = 2, adj = c(-.1, -.1))
abline(a = 0, b = 0.75, col = 2)
text(14.2,10, "-25% Line", col = 2, adj = c(-.1, -.1))
leg.txt <- c("SVR_rbf", "SVR_poly","ANFIS","NN")
legend(list(x = 2,y = 17.95), legend = leg.txt, col = 1:6, pch = c(19,20,3,4))
```

I changed the color of ANFIS that i want but in the table of labels the color of ANFIS did not changed. how should i changed it?
And if i wanna to add some text above of the plot in the plot tab what code i should add to my source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a title to your plot, use the argument

```
main="the title here"
```

inside your plot command, or if you're adding it afterwards, use

```
title("the title here").
```

---

Your problem with the colours in your legend is that you have four items in your legend:

```
("SVR_rbf", "SVR_poly","ANFIS","NN"),
```

but you are giving the plot command six colours:

```
col = 1:6.
```

Try doing

```
col=1:4
```

instead.

Comment: So,thanks for your guide about title. i did it as below:
title("esvr.rmse=0.301618754780172, esvr.rss=6.09524950675449",cex.main=0.95,col.main=1,font.main=1)

About color i change 1:6 to 1:4 but when i change the color in :
points(donnees.test$y,ANFIS, col=6,pch =3)
The color of ANFIS in table of plot did not changed.how is it?

Comment: `col=6` will plot all those points using the colour "6", which is pink. What colour do you want those points to be? Try
`col="black"` or `col=2` instead of `col=6`. Are they now different to what they were?

Comment: I changed the color to 6 : points(donnees.test$y,ANFIS, col=6,pch =3)
but the color of item in plot was changed . the color of that label in the label box did not change to col=6. where can i change that too?

Comment: Ah, in the legend. The legend is very much separate from the plot. To change the colours used in the legend, you must change the colours used in your legend command

`legend(list(x = 2,y = 17.95), legend = leg.txt, col = 1:6, pch = c(19,20,3,4))`.

Change `col=1:6` to `col=c(1, 2, 6, 4)`;

This should make the third item in your legend, `"ANFIS"`, coloured pink (colour 6).